# Swift 2 - Click on Image to load a new ViewController

Tags: swift2, viewcontroller, gesture, tap

I'm totally new to Xcode (Swift2).

What I want to achieve is when I click on an image which is on my `main.storyboard`, I want to open a new view controller or point it to a new view controller. How can I do this?

For example, I can do this using a button by dragging the button (Ctrl+right click) and pointing it to the new view controller at design time and it works great but I want to do this at the touch/tap of the image at run time.

Answer (score 0):

```
image.userInteractionEnabled = true

let tapRecog = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "imgTap:")
image.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecog)

func imgTap(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) 
{
    let tapImg = gestureRecognizer.view!

    let secondViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewViewController") as! NewViewController
    secondViewController.DisplayImg = tapImg  //NewViewController create DisplayImg UIImageView object
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Jayesh. Where do I add the first 3 lines? Also in the function imgTap, what is the code to navigate to specific view controller.

Comment: add in viewDidLoad()

Comment: Thank you @Jayesh. What does the code let tapImg= gestureRecognizer.view! do? Can you also share with the me the code to navigate to another view.

Comment: Thank you @Jayesh. This is exactly what I was looking. I shall try the code.

Comment: I'm getting an error at this line: secondViewController.DisplayImg = tapImg Value of type "InfoView" has no member "DisplayImg". I've got this line before: let secondViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("InfoView") as! InfoView