# Is is possible to click an imageView and open a new View Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

I'm new to IOS and learning the IDE at the moment. I was wondering if its possible to link an imageView, when clicked, to a View Controller

Comment: Pls take a  look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36277208/swift-2-click-on-image-to-load-a-new-viewcontroller coz it is quite similar. gl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure. First, in `viewDidLoad` of your `UIViewController` make it tappable:

```
imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Then assign the gesture recognizer:

```
imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.imageTap)))
```

Once the action is triggered, perform a transition to a new VC:

```
// Func in your UIViewController
@objc func imageTap() {
    // present modally
    self.present(YourNewViewController())
    // or push to the navigation stack
    self.navigationController?.push(YourNewViewController())
    // or perform segue if you use storyboards
    self.preformSegue(...)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is possible. You'll need to add a tap gesture recogniser to image view and in the function perform segue.

**SWIFT 4**

```
let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,action:Selector(“imageTapped”))
yourImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
yourImageView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
```

Function to handle Tap:

```
@objc func imageTapped() {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourNextScreen", sender: "")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can bind a tap gesture recognizer to your imageview. You can follow this link here on a previous answer on [how to do it programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880607/how-to-assign-an-action-for-uiimageview-object-in-swift)

You could do it completely in the interface builder by putting a UIButton, with a transparent background and no text, over the ImageView and then control drag the button to the viewcontroller you want to trigger a segue on touch.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is. You should add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the UIImageView and add a selector to trigger the pushing a new viewcontroller method.

For example;

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView! {
    didSet {
        let imageTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(imageTapGestureRecognizer)
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}

func imageTapped() {
    //navigate to another view controller
}
```

Comment: ok would i add the view controller method within the selector or in a func where the image is clicked

Comment: yes you should add your navigation code to imageTapped()

Answer (score 0):

add gesture and if you want to animate it [then see this pod](https://github.com/wxxsw/GSImageViewerController)

Comment: This question is outdated